# My app gets stopped unfortunately when I use Sugar ORM

Tags: android, sugarorm

Using these [configurations](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) I did add sugar orm to my project, but my application stopped unfortunately by this error :

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: gigacycle.geoaudiotag, PID: 22760
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.orm.SugarApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.orm.SugarApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/gigacycle.geoaudiotag-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/gigacycle.geoaudiotag-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:676)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.orm.SugarApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/gigacycle.geoaudiotag-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/gigacycle.geoaudiotag-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1004)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:666)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6289) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:221) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1860) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.orm.SugarApp
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

This is my Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gigacycle.geoaudiotag">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="geoaudiotagdb.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="gigacycle.geoaudiotag"/>
        <activity
            android:name="gigacycle.geoaudiotag.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

also this line is compiling successfully!

```
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.4'
```

I don't know why this fatal error occurred? where is my mistake?

Comment: Take out `android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"` from your application tag.

Comment: is it work? but this attribute recommended by sugar orm :http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html

Comment: sorry my bad.  you need that.  If you do gradle sync, and build. Does that still error out?

Comment: gradle builds successfully!

Comment: I did remove `android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"` from my application tag and that error does not appear.!!!!

Comment: Is that attribute not necessary?

Comment: The error would not appear if you remove but I guess ORM does not work without it.

Comment: now the error changed to `no such table:...`, but database version did not change!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141736/discussion-between-emma-and-younes-jafari).

Comment: thank you Emma! please post our result as an answer to others!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sync gradle and build.

Just download the package does not generate com.orm.SugarApp. Gradle sync will generate the class and before syncing, it appears as lint error in AndroidManifest.
Unfortunately this cannot be captured as compiler error and results in runtime error as you get.

[image]